# Swift clear console

Tags: swift, console

I am currently making a command line application in swift 2 which shows the user options on what they can do, after they select an action, I would like to clear the console.

How would I simulate the bash `clear` command in swift without using `system()`?

If I run `system("clear")` in Xcode I get the following error:

```
TERM environment variable not set.
```

I know that I would not get this issue when running the script in terminal, I would just like to make my script 100% swift 2